# Is there a way to implement the Forwarding Object pattern in Java without boilerplate code?

Tags: java, dry, encapsulation

Since encapsulation is considered better than inheritance (according to Effective Java and other sources), there is a pattern of Forwarding an Object.  (I believe the Decorator pattern is a synonym for this, but please don't yell at me if I'm wrong!)

Basically, you write code like this:

```
class public ForwardSomething extends Something {
   private Something something=new Something();
   public void somethingMethod1(){return  something.somethingMethod1();}
   public void somethingMethod2(){return  something.somethingMethod2();}
   /*Do same for the methods for all methods of Something that exist when you wrote      Forward Something.*/
}
```

So there's a lot of boilerplate code.  And we all know "Don't Repeat Yourself" is ideal.  Is there a good way to approach this problem, that doesn't involve the boilerplate code?

Comment: (If it extends Something, you already has its methods--what's the purpose of compositing a subclass? Do you mean implements, and a new SomethingImpl, rather than what you'vecwritten here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With interfaces you could use a [dynamic proxy class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) or with concrete classes you can do some trickery like dynamically writing the bytecode for a new subclass with [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) (or similar like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/))

Comment: I wouldn't recommend homespun byte code treachery when projects already exist.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: No, not trivially. It's Java.

Most IDEs can do this automatically. I've resorted to "boilerplate baseclasses" to avoid polluting the code-that-does-real-work when I'm doing a lot of it.

You could use [Lombok's](http://projectlombok.org/) [`@Delegate` (docs)](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html), though.